# The modern way to use threaded coredata

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

In the past times, we use coredata as [Apple ask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1), one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread, use `NSNotificationCenter` to observe the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, then merge changes back. Apple show us the right way in it's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html).

How ever, it's a little verbose, you must write a bunch of code to make it work.iOS 5 was shipped with the new method `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` for `NSManagedObjectContext`. Now it's possible to pass a single `NSManagedObjectContext` to all threads, and use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` to wrap all coredata related code, it should be much more easier and less headache, yet people seems did't talk about this new way a lot, even Apple itself, the "Concurrency with Core Data" chapter of iOS documentation  and "ThreadedCoreData" sample code still recommend one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread.

So I'm wondering, is there any downside for `performBlock(AndWait):` makes people don't use it? Or the "new way" I said is just a bad design?

Comment: Magical Record is a good Framework for dealing with Private / Main Contexts and merging them: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Answer (score 2):

In reality, it is still true that you can only have one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread.

If you carefully read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html):

> Private queue (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType).
>
> The context creates and manages a private queue. Instead of you creating and managing a thread or queue with which a context is associated, here the context owns the queue and manages all the details for you (provided that you use the block-based methods as described below).

this means that a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context also handles an operation queue for you, but you cannot share that context between different threads.
This is particularly relevant in case you need to access the context from your UI, which would require having a second context of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

So, you may have cases where the new `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` operations make things easier as to multithreaded access to Core Data (e.g., a long running task fetching remote data and updating the db), but in the end, the big picture remains the same: one context per thread.

I think it is better to keep this clear in mind to avoid ugly surprises.

As to merging changes, you can use `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` with the old confinement model (you handle the thread or operation queue), or you can use the newer parent-child context relationship where `saveContext` pushes the changes from the child context to the parent. (thanks to flexaddicted for commenting about parent-child contexts).

Comment: What do you mean with *the big picture remains the same*? If you use parent-child contexts, notifications are not useful anymore. thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment. I was simply focusing too much on the `performBlock` part of the question, and thus defined the "big picture" based on that. But you are right that parent-child contexts make explicit merging unnecessary. I extended my answer to take your remark into account.

Comment: Thanks, I already knows that `NSManagedObjectContext` should be one per thread, `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait` doesn't change that, but it actually makes things easier, so I'm wondering why people doesn't talk about it much, because it will break the compatibility for iOS 4 and below?

Comment: IMO, while `performBlock` makes things easier, multithreading is inherently complex and `performBlock` is no silver bullet. In fact, it is just that you do not have to manage a thread yourself and implement a notification action... not much, really...

Comment: @PrideChung You should ask to them ;) See my *about your question...* answer. Yes, of course. New data stuff is available in iOS 5 and greater. But it's only a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> Now it's possible to pass a single `NSManagedObjectContext` to all threads, and use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` to wrap all coredata related

What do you mean with this? The goal of new Core Data stuff, among other things, it's to create a parent-child relationship where changes at the client level can be easily pulled directly to the parent. **Each thread will have its own context**. Obviously the limitation about `NSManagedObject`s remains. When you need to share objects among threads, you need to share theirs `NSManagedObjectID`s.

What differ respect to the previous approach is that `performBlock` (and its sync version) allows you to not worry about threaded environments. Use them to do stuff and Core Data will manage things for you.

About your question, for example, I don't use new stuff in my old Core Data projects because they require a code reorganization. Obviously, this strictly depends on how bigger projects are. But if you start a new project, you should try them. They are very challenging!

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression, but you got my point. I'm trying to share one and only one `NSManagedObjectContext` for every thread, for other threads(not the one created `NSManagedObjectContext`) I intend to use `performBlock:` to make sure any code access `NSManagedObjectContext` or `NSManagedObject` runs in the right thread. This seems much more easier than using `NSNotification` to track changes.

Comment: Would there be any problem if we used a single NSManagedObjectContext initialized with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType on multiple threads if we would do all operations inside performBlock and we would not pass NSManagedObjects outside of that block (but for example convert them to a dictionaries or other non managed objects and pass that objects outside of the block instead of managed objects)?